# module.export in typescript. import json list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, export

It seems simple, this operates in javascript, but I'm a bit confused about typescript's closest equivalent. I'm trying to use module.exports in the way I know from javascript, passing data the json list data between 3 files.

in javascript the main file basically works as this: -
main.js :

```
const { mainnet: addresses } = require("./addresses");

const token0 = addresses.tokens.busd;
```

so, main.ts would be? (i believe main issue is here):

```
import  { mainnet } from "./addresses/index";

token0 = mainnet.tokens.busd;
```

then typescript index.ts in ./address/index.ts (i believe this functions properly):

```
import  tokensMainnet  from './tokens-mainnet.json';

declare var module: any;
// "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" = true
module.exports = {
  mainnet: {
    tokens: tokensMainnet
  }
};
```

and tokensmainnet.json

```
{
  "busd": "0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56",
  "wbnb": "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"
}
```

i can see from the metadata it's functioning:

[image]

so I believe the main problem with with importing this module in the main.ts

I've grazed over some sources such as with no luck https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in typescript

add

```
"resolveJsonModule":true
```

to  package.json:

" Allows importing modules with a ‘.json’ extension, which is a common practice in node projects. This includes generating a type for the import based on the static JSON shape."  -https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolveJsonModule

so add to main.ts:

```
import * as data from "./addresses/tokens-mainnet.json" 
    //...program code...
constructor(){
 let tokenAddress = data
    console.log(tokenAddress.busd)

}
```

:)